# Event listeners in Table

Tags: javascript, .net, razor, dom-events

I'm trying to create an aggregated table in which the subordinate elements would sum up to their parent elements. Each element contains a class that is equal to the id of its parent element. I have added event listener to every element of the table, so that the summation would go upwards the tree.
The code looks roughly as follows:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("item.AmountY0");
for (i = 1; i < (x.length - 3); i++) {
   x[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      if (x[i].tagName == "TD") {
         document.getElementById("y0_" + x[i].className).innerHTML =
            String(parseInt(document.getElementById("y0_" + x[i].className).innerHTML) + parseInt(x[i].innerHTML));
      }
      if (x[i].tagName == "INPUT") {
         document.getElementById("y0_" + x[i].className).innerHTML =
            String(parseInt(document.getElementById("y0_" + x[i].className).innerHTML) + parseInt(x[i].value));
      }
   }, false);
};
```

When I check the individual table elements in console, the direct parent element gets updated, but not the other grand-parents. However, when I run the page, nothing happens (and no errors are reported).

The corresponding HTML code is as follows:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
                string y0_id = "y0_" + item.AlphaCode;
                string class_parent = item.ParentCode;
                string class_parent_right = item.ParentCode + " " + item.CssClassAmt;

                <tr class="@item.CssClassRow">
                    <td hidden="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullSymbol)</td>
                    <td hidden="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlphaCode)</td>
                    <td hidden="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentCode)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Symbol)</td>
                    <td class="@item.CssClassCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionName)</td>

                    @if (item.IsFinal[0].Equals('0')) {
                        <td id=@y0_id class=@class_parent style="text-align: right; width: 120px;" name="item.AmountY0">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountY0)</td>                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.AmountY0, new { @id = y0_id, @class = class_parent, @style = "text-align: right; width: 120px;"})</td>
                    }

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.FinNote, new { @class = item.CssClassNote })</td>
                    <td><a id="js-modal-prompt" class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-small" style="line-height: 19px" href="#">+</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). You can fix it using:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("item.AmountY0");
for (i = 1; i < (x.length - 3); i++) {
   (function() {
      var elm = document.getElementById("y0_" + x[i].className);
      x[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
         if (x[i].tagName == "TD") {
            elm.innerHTML = String(parseInt(elm.innerHTML) + parseInt(x[i].innerHTML));
         }
         if (x[i].tagName == "INPUT") {
            elm.innerHTML = String(parseInt(elm.innerHTML) + parseInt(x[i].value));
         }
      }, false);
   }());
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped partially: i.e. the direct parent gets updated automatically, but not the grandparents ;(

Comment: Can you update your post and share an example of direct parent & grandparents that you need to update. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there's no more relevant code to show. The `ParentCode` contains the id of the parent element - and it goes up to 5 levels above. I thought that when I update the last child element, then this change would propagate up to the top.